# warning - @return tag has no arguments

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have 2 Warnings : 
--The First is  : HELPDESKGESTION2\src\java\glpi\action\LoginAction.java:37: warning - @return tag has no arguments.
--The second is : HELPDESKGESTION2\src\java\glpi\actionform\UtilisateurActionForm.java:67: warning - @return tag has no arguments.

The Code is :

```
@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    UtilisateurActionForm utiAF =(UtilisateurActionForm) form;
    Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
    utilisateur.setLogin(utiAF.getLogin());
    utilisateur.setPassword(utiAF.getPassword());
    IUtilisateurBO IutiBO = (IUtilisateurBO) ServiceFinder.getContext(request).getBean("UtilisateurBO");
    if (IutiBO.checkLogin(utilisateur)==true){
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
        }
    return mapping.findForward(ERROR);
}
```

Comment: What's line 37 of `LoginAction` and line 67 of `UtilisateurActionForm`?

Answer (score 1):

the only @return that i'm aware of is javadoc. are you sure your "warnings" aren't generated by you ide to make sure you document your code properly?

Comment: when I deploy my project it displays an error, and therefore does not delpoy. that's why I generated javadoc, to know the problem, and that the message was displayed, what is the solution please?

Comment: because of this warning : HELPDESKGESTION2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: The module has not been deployed.

Comment: well, for javadoc simply add the necessary arguments to the @return (whatever that might by, i'ts your documentation) the javadoc should still be generated even without them.

Answer (score 1):

@return is the javadoc for the methods return value. Can you check if the javadocs in the java file has an description for thr return comments. e.g.

```
* @return num squared.
```